# How to ordering by specific rules django

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x

I want to order my objects in django by this rule:

- All `characters` with `is_sold == True` must be in the end of query result.

I am use two query, to get both sold and not sold characters:

```
characters = list(Character.objects.all().filter(is_sold=False).order_by('server__ranking'))
characters += list(Character.objects.filter(is_sold=True).order_by('server__ranking'))
```

Can i do this using only one query using `order_by`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass multiple fields to `order_by`:

```
characters = Character.objects.order_by('is_sold', 'server__ranking')
```

Whether the sold come before the unsold depends on your database backend, as some databases order `False` before `True` and some the other way round (see [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19726))! So you might have to do instead:

```
characters = Character.objects.order_by('-is_sold', 'server__ranking')
```

Comment: and if you use `order_by` there is no need `all()`